# Access customer information using Square Connect API

Tags: square-connect

Is it possible to access any information about a merchant's customers using the Square Connect API? The most ideal piece of information would be the email address customers enter for their receipt, but but some type of unique customer id would be nice to determine repeat customers.

Looking through the [Square Connect API Documents](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api) there are no endpoints for customers and Payment objects do not include any of this information. Is there another Square API with this capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at this time. Regarding customer email addresses obtained for receipts, from the [Square help center](https://squareup.com/help/article/3834):

> Based on our privacy policies and governing regulations, we cannot share cardholders' personal information with our customers when contact information is only collected for receipt purposes.

However, I'll pass this feedback along to the Connect API engineering team (I write the docs).

Comment: Thank you for the complete and fast answer! That makes sense in lieu of your privacy policy. I know quite a few merchants would probably enjoy the capability of asking their clients to sign up for the mail list however, because it's a great way to stay in touch with our customer base.

Comment: Does this policy also apply to the customer's name? I can see the customer's name on the receipt but it's not provided by API endpoints. That said, the API provides a link to the receipt so I guess I could scrape the name from it if I'm forced to.

Answer (score 10):

This is now possible as of V2 and the `transaction.tenders.customer_id` attribute.

In my use case I am attempting to get the customer from a webhook notification.  As I see it, there are few steps required for this scenario:

1. Issue the v1 request for the Payment using the webhook entity_id

   - `/v1/{location_id}/payments/{payment_id}`
2. Issue the v2 request for the Transaction using the id returned on the Payment object.  The only place the v2 transaction id is located is on the last part of the path in the `payment_url` attribute.

   - `/v2/locations/{location_id}/transactions/{transactionId}`
3. Issue the v2 request for the Customer identified on the Payment tender(s).  If there are multiple tenders the customerId *should* be the same for each.

   - `/v2/customers/{transaction.tenders[0].customer_id}`

If you have the customer_id in hand oviously you can skip straight to step 3.

Comment: End of 2019 and the customer_id is not in 'transaction.tenders[0]' anymore. No clue how to tie the customer's info and transaction together. Did you update this somehow?