# Square Connect API customer_id not populated when Listing Transactions

Tags: square-connect

I am using v2 of the connect api to list transactions for a specific date range.  All of the transactions that I get back never have the customer_id populated in any of the Tender objects even though I know some customers are known by square.  I am able to successfully retrieve all of the other data.  The resource I am using is locations/{location_id}/transactions and specifying the begin_time and end_time in the query string .  What am I missing?

Edit

I downloaded my transactions using the export function and none of the transactions have a customer name or Id.  What is required to have this information populated?  Maybe that is where I am going wrong.  Does this have to be a customer I add myself or does it include customers added by Square?  Is it required the customer to have their receipt sent to them by email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently figured out how to retrieve customer information, I recorded it here: [Access customer information using Square Connect API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899848/access-customer-information-using-square-connect-api/37078371#37078371)

Assuming that you've actually recorded a customer on the sale, the customer_id should be present on each of your tenders...

> Issue the v2 request for the Customer identified on the Payment tender(s). If there are multiple tenders the customerId should be the same for each.
>   /v2/customers/{transaction.tenders[0].customer_id}

Note: I also reported a similar issue: [customer_id is not populated on transaction tender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308423/customer-id-is-not-populated-on-transaction-tender)  and for a few days Square acknowleged in the comments that there were going to fix it.  Then they seemingly deleted the comment from SO.  As of testing I was doing last night, all transactions had the customer_id populated in real time.

Good Luck!

Comment: I am still not able to pull any customer ids from the transaction even if I pull in the transaction directly by transaction id.  How do I verify that the transaction I am pulling back should have customer id on there?  Maybe I need to start there.

Comment: You have to add the customer to the sale, this may help: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5532-manage-your-customer-directory-from-the-square-app

Comment: This comment helped.  I added a customer manually and associated them with a sale and I was able to see it when i requested the transaction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the *customer_id* field in the [charge request](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-charge)? The customer ID should be returned in the transaction object if the association is specified at charge time.

Comment: I am using Square Register to charge customers.  My understanding is that Square Register would associate a transaction for a customer if either they use a credit card or they enter their email address in at the end of the transaction, but that does not seem to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable customer management for the merchant, add then add a customer to the sale.

This may help: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5532-manage-your-customer-directory-from-the-square-app